# How to end custom game with 2 players

Tags: league-of-legends

I was trying out some things with a friend in a custom game. There were just the 2 of us.

Normally when I do it alone, I can exit the game, and then I can join a new game, since previous one disappears.

However, when there are 2 of us in a custom game, even if we both exit the game, it won't end. Meaning we can't join a different game. We either have to wait 20 minutes to /ff or destroy a nexus before that.

**Question:**
How can we end a custom game prematurely?

Comment: You're sure that when you've both left the match, it doesn't end it?  That sounds like a bug, it's supposed to end when no one is in it.

Comment: @Namfuak We both exited several times and it wouldnt end the game. We were forced to play for 20 minutes. I guess I ll edit my question if more people can confirm that it is a bug.

Comment: It is a bug, you can try to exit and reload the client, or if that doesn't work, email riot support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that is not supposed to happen. When a game has no more players in it the game is supposed to end because the server has no reason to keep the game alive when no one is in that game. You should email Riot support and tell them the problem, maybe with some screen shots including the time in the game (hopefully you won't get a auto-response back).